# Determining what user data fields to protect within a database?

Tags: mysql, database-design, security, encryption

Besides passwords, credit/debit card info, social security info, passport info, what other types of data fields should be hashed to give it an additional layer of protection within any database?

Should the personal names, email, phone number, date of birth, and home address of the users also be hashed?

And does performance slow down on read and retrieval of values from the database if all values are hashed?

Comment: Passwords can be handled by a one-way hash (eg md5); most other things you need to "encrypt", not "hash", so that you can recover the original value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Protecting the users data in your database, is probably the most important thing you can do. However, it has to work with the application as well. If you go and hash all the data, how will you display it as human-readable text to the user. Basically you cant. Hashing can be used for one-way verification and to some degree anonymization.

Asking the question `which data should i protect?` is propably more relevant. How you should protect it, depends on your technology-stack combined with regulatory requirements. Here PII data (Personally identifiable information) is a really good place to start. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personally_identifiable_information

It also depends on the field of work, in which your application runs. You might have state/country regulativs you need to comply with. Healthcare systems tend to have other requirements for data protection, then public forums etc etc. And if you have european users, you must implement the GDPR regulative requirements https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Data_Protection_Regulation

So basically, you need to find out what you need to comply with in your given situation and take it from there.Hope this helps